# How can I extract the code repetition here?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, dry

I am trying to extract out the common code pattern here in an extract method, but am having trouble finding the proper type for the type of Presenter.  Any help?

```
public bool CanGotoHome 
{ 
    get { return !(CurrentPresenter is IHomePresenter) && IsLoggedIn; } 
}
public bool CanGotoImportanceOfAimsAndObjectives 
{ 
    get { return !(CurrentPresenter is IImportanceOfAimsAndObjectivesPresenter) && IsLoggedIn; } 
}
public bool CanGotoGotoAimsAndObjectives 
{ 
    get { return !(CurrentPresenter is IAimsAndObjectivesPresenter) && IsLoggedIn; } 
}
```

Comment: btw, I would check IsLoggedIn first and only after that - check the type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use Generics

```
private bool SomeFuncName<T>()
{
    return !(CurrentPresenter is T) && IsLoggedIn;
}
```

usage:

```
public bool CanGotoGotoAimsAndObjectives { 
    get { return SomeFuncName<IAimsAndObjectivesPresenter>(); } 
}
```

Comment: A good func name in this case would be CanGoTo, which would result in
return CanGoTo<IHomePresenter>();

Comment: @Luke, Thanks for the syntax help, @Darko, good idea for method name. :)

Comment: @Luke, actually I do love them, because I always end up getting more rep when I am randomly downvoted, because people see it and upvote, which is then a net greater amount of rep for me :)

Comment: hehe that's an amusing thought. On a side note, I hope my code works, I didn't test it :)

Answer (score 2):

To me, it would seem easier if the object just knew how it should act.

```
class BasePresenter
{
    public bool CanGotoHome 
    { 
        get { return IsLoggedIn; } 
    }
}

class HomePresenter : BasePresenter
{
    public bool CanGotoHome 
    { 
        get { return False; } 
    }
}
```

And then do the same for the other methods. This seems much simpler and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks strange in general... If there are only those 3 lines, why bother creating a general method to refactor them? It's not going to save you that much repetition.

OTOH, if there are more, then this code looks like typical capabilities / permission querying. If you have more than 3 types and those functions can get more complex in other cases, then why not just load those into a `presenter_capabilities` database table (or even AD, if you're in an enterprisey system...)? Check whether "Capability-based security" isn't what you're really looking for.

As for the code itself, I'd go for something like:

```
public bool GetCapability(Caps cap) { 
   return IsLoggedIn && CapabilityResolver.Check(CurrentPresenter, cap);
   // or even
   // return CapabilityResolver.Check(CurrentPresenter, cap, IsLoggedIn);
}

// usage
whatever.GetCapability(Caps.CanGoHome);
```

Saves you from recompiling if the rules get more complicated, or if you add any new caps / interfaces. If they are pretty much static, you can just resolve them through some hash.

Comment: Thanks for your two cents, I'll reflect on it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code sample, I would be a bit tempted to use the inbuilt principal / role definitions here, and some string constants:

```
static bool IsInRole(string role) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(role)) return true;
    IPrincipal principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    return principal == null ? false : principal.IsInRole(role);
}
public bool CanGotoHome   
    get { IsInRole(AccessRights.GotoHome); } 
}
```

although maybe this just shifts the responsibility to creating an appropriate custom principal...